# Node.js socket hang up when agent is present

Tags: node.js

I have the following setup:
Client => Proxy server => Origin Server

I'm using the following Node.js libraries for each of these pieces, respectively: 
isomorphic-fetch => http-proxy => http

Here's a gist of the setup in two files, one for each of the servers and one for the client: https://gist.github.com/headquarters/850cbb199ff397c6da56fb8d86113a7e
To run this locally, run `node server.js` in one shell and `node fetch.js` in another shell.

With the servers running, if I go to `http://localhost:8818` in a browser, I get the sample response `{"a":"b"}`, so that's working. If I go to `http://localhost:9818`, I *also* get that response, so the proxying appears to be working fine. However, if I run `DEBUG=* node fetch.js`, which includes the HTTP proxy agent, the request fails (see output at https://gist.github.com/headquarters/850cbb199ff397c6da56fb8d86113a7e#file-failure-txt).

Without the `agent` property, the fetch command works fine on the command line. How do I go about debugging this socket hang up error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't read the [https-proxy-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-proxy-agent) docs closely enough. This line was a bit confusing: `An HTTP(s) proxy http.Agent implementation for HTTPS`--the PROXY itself can be either HTTP or HTTPS, but the origin server has to be HTTPS for this flavor of proxy-agent. For an HTTP origin server, I had to use [http-proxy-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-agent). Thus, the socket hang up was probably coming from https.Agent trying to access an HTTP endpoint. It worked when I switched to http-proxy-agent.